# How can we create a search form to display a specific node

Tags: views

I need to create a result publishing system in drupal.

there must be a search page to enter the student register number.

when the user enter the register number it should take it to a single specific node.

here the register number is a nodeid

so when a user enter the node id and hit show button, it should display that specific node.

which method is best.

i think with views we can do this.

but how

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make an exposed filter (with autocomplete) of the register number in your view (showing all these desired nodes), enable it's exposed filter block (Advanced > Exposed form in block : Yes)

Now place this block where ever you want, hit apply, you should be taken to the views page, only showing one result. (Make sure the full rendered node entity is shown)